# WordPress Admin - POSTs not being added to MySQL database. Edits and trashing works

Tags: wordpress, admin, posts

https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Files#WordPress_Root

I was hoping someone could share some ideas on where to look to find the issue. I checked `post.php` and `post-new.php` in the root directory but can't seem to find what is handling the injection of posts to the database.

The database is configured correctly because we're able to edit and delete posts via WordPress.

When entering a post and submitting the form, it goes through to the next page without any PHP errors and such. But the post is never added to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the database user has "all" privileges granted to it for the database in use. Use the Database manager in your host's Cpanel.

Privileges are typically:

> ALL PRIVILEGES - this allows a MySQL user all access to a designated
>   database **(this is what you want)**
>
> CREATE - allows them to create new tables or databases
>
> DROP - allows them to them to delete tables or databases
>
> DELETE - allows them to delete rows from tables
>
> INSERT - allows them to insert rows into tables
>
> SELECT - allows them to use the Select command to read through
>   databases
>
> UPDATE - allow them to update table rows
>
> GRANT OPTION - allows them to grant or remove other users' privileges